# Round Robin scheduler with multiple games/rounds each night seperated by given duration

Tags: php

Trying to create a schedule generator that allows games to be played on same night, spaced by a given duration (7 days is current value).

```
    $data = [
        'season' => $this->request->getPost('season'),
        'teams' => $this->request->getPost('teams[]'),
        'days' => $this->request->getPost('days[]'),
        'start' => $this->request->getPost('start'),
        'gameTimes' => $this->request->getPost('gameTimes[]'),
    ];
    
    dd($data);
    $teamslist = $data['teams'];
    $startDate = $data['start'];

    //if odd number of teams add a BYE team!
    if (count($teamslist)%2 != 0)
    { 
        array_push($teamslist,"IGNORE"); 
    } 
    
    shuffle($teamslist);

    $away = array_splice($teamslist,(count($teamslist)/2)); 
    $home = $teamslist; 
    

    //iterate through for every game in every round for teams
    for ($i = 0; $i < ((count($teamslist)+count($away))-1); $i++)
    {
        //shuffle the list so its random
        for ($j = 0; $j<count($home); $j++)
        {
            //assign the relevant teams, dates, times and referee to fixtures
            if (($i%2 != 0) && ($j%2 == 0))
            { 
                if ($j%2 == 0)
                {
                    $startDate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($startDate));
                }

                $match[$i][$j]["Home"]=$away[$j]; 
                $match[$i][$j]["Away"]=$home[$j]; 
                $match[$i][$j]["Date"]=$startDate;
                $match[$i][$j]["Time"]="10:00:00";
            } 

            else 
            { 
                if ($j%2==0)
                {
                    $startDate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($startDate));
                }

                $match[$i][$j]["Home"]=$away[$j]; 
                $match[$i][$j]["Away"]=$home[$j]; 
                $match[$i][$j]["Date"]=$startDate;
                $match[$i][$j]["Time"]="10:00:00";
            } 
        } 

        //If there
        if(count($home)+count($away)-1 > 2)
        { 
            $splice=array_splice($home,1,1);
            $shift=array_shift($splice);
            array_unshift($away,$shift); 
            array_push($home,array_pop($away)); 
        } 
        $startDate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($startDate."+7 days"));
        
    }   

    //go through the whole array storing everything and go to each round, then game and check whether our bye team is present, if so ignore and remove the fixture,else keep it
    foreach($match as $matchkey => $matchval)
    {
        foreach($matchval as $gamekey=>$game)
        {
            if($game["Home"]!= "IGNORE" && $game["Away"]!="IGNORE")
            {
                //store it all in a new multidimensional array 
                $allmatches[$matchkey][$gamekey]=$game;
            }
        }   

    }
```

$data displayed is[image]

Current output is [image]

I am trying to have the number of games each team plays per night equal to
count($data['gameTimes'])

I have tried placing foreach with $data['gameTimes'] in multiple areas and it isnt creating exactly what I am looking for... at a loss.

Comment: Get a database.

Comment: That's where all the team Ids are coming from, thanks for the amazing assistance though.

Comment: So WTF are you loading all this into PHP's RAM for? Where is your schema?